# Family budget or expense-money tracker dataset

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for some family budget or expense tracker large dataset, in any format, to have some sample data to test an application on large scale.

**The dataset must have the detailed records of any payment, I'm not interested in aggregated data**, since it is the job my application has to do.

**I would love to have something with those columns: `date, type, description, amount (of the single transaction)`**, [like in this template I have found online](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W0qDEbyLMKphmzW-H9KR9SXYiKP87Y102f7IY0-1ou4/template/preview), which unfortunatly does not come with any data, **BUT with single transactions instead of subtotals**:

[image]

Maybe I'm missing some important keyword or just searching in the wrong place.
Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

After searching for some hours I found [this dummy data link](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=comments&redir_token=QUFFLUhqa05FYWlvWWlZSEJDSlZTRHVnQy04RDFTMmZOUXxBQ3Jtc0tsR2I5d3VTY0pxSjlKbExsbHBMVE9EQ3F5S3BWblVTR1FrWTZYTlBmbjJuRUJnZlFqalJBUDBQS0VZZXZNXzZwS3dXcUY2bjQwQV9HX0ZPYnVBa2tuV3YwcS1kd3FzQVpwRy1EYWFUdnZBYTJ0VEpKOA&q=https%3A%2F%2Frockstarexcel.com%2Fexpense-tracker-alternate-dummy-data%2F&stzid=UgxXOgsOl76hzS3CsFZ4AaABAg.9PU_VE59c7l9Prx7ujgE2p) from a youtube video on [how to create an expense tracker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZMuRh7p8k0), if anybody can provide a better dataset it would be very useful!

For those who don't want to open the link, this is how the data looks like (**as I said I'm more interested in something like the image I posted above with also payment type and a description, and the "vendor" column isn't interesting for me, but this was the "best" I've found**):

[image]

Comment: Do you want a row for each transaction (for instance 3 rows if I go 3 times to my local grocery), or aggregated data (for instance the sum of every time I went to that grocery or even to any grocery)?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul thanks for your question, I edited my question to make it more clear. I want to have a dataset with every transaction

Answer (score 1):

### [Household Budget Survey](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/household-budget-surveys)

The Household Budget Survey(HBS), is a national survey focusing on households' expenditure on goods and services, giving a picture of living conditions in the European Union (EU). It is carried out by each Member State and is used to compile weightings for important macroeconomic indicators, such as consumer price indices (used as measures of inflation) and national accounts.

They were launched in most EU Member States at the beginning of the 1960's and Eurostat has been collecting and publishing these survey data every five years since 1988. The two last collection rounds (waves) were 2010 and 2015.

Find More at [here](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/household-budget-surveys)

[Database Link](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/household-budget-surveys/database)

---

- [Household income and expenditure surveys](https://www.ilo.org/surveyLib/index.php/catalog/HIES/?page=1&ps=15&repo=HIES)
- [Household Budget Survey - Istat](https://www.istat.it/en/archivio/180353)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited my question because I hadn't said that I'm not searching some aggregated data, but I need a large dataset with every transaction (please check my edit). I tried to open the files in the links you provided but I could find just aggregated data, please tell me if I'm wrong